How to get PivotFields AutoShow method to work in Python using win32?
I'm working on automating an Excel file using Python's win32com.client library. My goal is to create an Excel file that will look and function as if someone had manually done all the work within Excel.  When trying to use the AutoShow method to display the top 10 entries based on a pivot field, but I keep encountering the following error:
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
Details:

The AutoSort method works as expected, but the AutoShow method fails with this error.
The field I'm trying to use AutoShow on exists in the pivot table and is accessible.
Here is a simplified version of the code that will produce the same error:

import win32com.client
import logging

# Set up basic configuration for logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler('output.log'),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ]
)

# Create a logger
logger = logging.getLogger('MyApp')

try:
    # Open Excel application
    excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = True

    # Open the workbook
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(r"C:/Users/.../temp.xlsx")  # File path to Excel Spreadsheet
    worksheet = workbook.Sheets('Top 10 Incomes')  # Adjust the sheet name as needed

    # Access the pivot table
    pivot_table = worksheet.PivotTables('PivotTable1')  # Adjust the pivot table name as needed

    # Apply the AutoShow method
    pivot_table.PivotFields("People").AutoShow(Type=-4105, Range=1, Count=10, Field="AnnualIncome")

    logger.info("AutoShow method applied successfully.")

except Exception as e:
    logger.error("An error occurred: %s", e)
    raise

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this would be appreciated!
What I Have Tried:

Verified that the PivotField("People") exists in the pivot table.
The AutoSort method works fine, but AutoShow consistently throws the error.
Referred to the official AutoShow documentation, and am confident that my parameters are aligned with the VBA syntax.
Tried using different fields, but get the same error.
Used Type=1 and other variations for the parameters, same error
Verified there are thousands of rows, so filtering 10 is not exceeding that

I expect that when this works, it would filter/shorten the pivot table to display only 10 results, instead of all the results.
Questions:

Am I passing the correct parameters to AutoShow?
Is there something I’m missing about the order or data type of the parameters?
Could this error relate to an issue with the specific data field ("AnnualIncome") being summarized in the pivot table?

I have reviewed these and they do not answer my question:
Experiment with Autoshow method, Excel VBA, Value top 10, Error 1004
Excel Vba, create pivot table, autoshow by value top 10, error 1004
